# localStorage: Storing Objects vs Simple Data Types in different ways?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen the approach of using **JSON.stringify and JSON.parse** to store and retrieve values/objects from HTML5 localStorage. **It works, but it "stringifies" everything** - including strings, numbers, etc. I'd like to improve it. I'd like to avoid "stringifying" simple data types that are not objects. I've got a method below that I use to determine if a parameter is an object and JSON.stringify it if it is an object.

```
lsSet: function(key, value) {

  ((Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]')) 
    ? localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value)) 
    : localStorage.setItem(key,value);
  return (localStorage.getItem(key)) ? true : false;
},
```

Is there a good way to identify if a localStorage string you are retrieving is a stringified object? I was thinking of checking if the string starts with { and ends with }, but it seems like there must be a better approach. Below is my current localStorage get method, but throws errors when trying to JSON.parse simple data types such as string.

```
lsGet: function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
},
```

Typical console error is due to to the JSON.parse:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
```

Any ideas? A thought just came to mind, maybe just a try/catch?

```
var value;
try {
  value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
} catch(err) {
  value = localStorage.getItem(key);
}
return value;
```

Edit: Note, I'm juggling a lot of different data around and I don't really want to have to worry about the typeof data I'm setting/getting. Thus stardard lsSet/lsGet methods were created. In my app, data is stored in PHP Session, JavaScript Objects and localStorage - a bit of a mix.

Comment: Shouldn't you know what you are putting into local storage? Why would you not know what you are retrieving when your application put it there?

Comment: why are you not using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: please provide value of `localStorage.getItem(key)` when error occurs so we can check why there is error while parsing.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - lots of data types. I don't want to have to worry about the typeof I'm setting. Thus a standard lsGet/lsSet

Comment: @sabithpocker - typeof can not be used for the data coming from localStorage.

Comment: you have to add an extra `"` if `typeof value === 'string'`. I mean using typeof when saving.

Comment: @sabithpocker - I understand the error. A simple value such as "English" (without quotes) throws the error when I try to JSON.parse() it.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't seem to cast numbers to strings... what data types is it handling wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try to write a string that happens to look like a stringified object or array? E.g. `var myString = '[1,2]'`. How will you know that you should return the string, not parse it into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to know whether a string your retrieve is intended to be a serialized object or a plain string, *except based on your own rules*. The strings `"null"`, `"34"`, `"[1,2,3]"` could all be valid strings or valid JSON, and unless you have an idea of expected content there is no way to be sure.

So I'd suggest either:

- Serialize and deserialize everything. This shouldn't be too bad performance-wise unless you're doing it at very high frequencies (in which case maybe localStorage is the wrong choice).

OR

- Add a custom "header" to your serialized strings, e.g. `"JSON:{...}"`. Then, when you retrieve a string, check for the header and process accordingly.

Comment: "Serialize and deserialize everything." - seems like the best advice. Is this the most common approach you see with localStorage get/set?

Comment: I think so, if you're dealing with a bunch of arbitrary data. IMO this is a case where you need to balance the potential performance hit of (de)serialization against the added complexity of dealing differently with different data types; unless performance is a big issue for you, simplicity wins. Localizing get/set in a single place means you can always upgrade to a complex, higher-performance option if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsSet: function(key, value) {
  switch(typeof value){
      case "string" : localStorage.setItem(key,'"' + value + '"'); break;
      case "number" : localStorage.setItem(key,value); break;
      case "object" : localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value)); break;
  }
  return (localStorage.getItem(key)) ? true : false;
},
```

just an idea not tested