# How to convert the data into different types when retrieving from local storage

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, web-storage

I am writing a little library to manipulate the data in localStorage.

**Below is the code snippet :**

```
function AppStorage (appName) {
    "use strict";

    var prefix  = appName;

    var saveItem = function (key, value) {

        if (!key || !value) {

            console.error("Missing parameters \"key\" and \"value\"");    

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {

            try {
                if (typeof value === 'Object') localStorage.setItem(prefix + '_' + key, JSON.stringify(value));
                if (typeof value === 'string') localStorage.setItem(prefix + '_' + key, value);

                return true;

            } catch (e) {

                return false;

            }

        } else  {

            return false;

        }

    }

    var getItem = function (key) {

        if (!key) {

            console.error("Missing parameter \"key\"");    

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {
            try {

                return localStorage.getItem(prefix + '_' + key);                

            } catch (e) {

                return false;

            }

        } else  {

            return false;

        }

    }

    var removeItem = function (key) {

        if (!key) {

            console.error("Missing parameter \"key\"");

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {

            try {
                localStorage.removeItem(prefix + '_' + key);
                return true;

            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }

        } else  {

            console.log("Browser does not support HTML5 Web Storage");

        }

    }

    return {
        set: function (key, value) {
            return saveItem(key, value);
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return getItem(key);
        },
        remove: function (key) {
            return removeItem(key);
        }
    }

}

var as = new AppStorage ('MyApp');
```

How ever im stuck with the following two issues.

1) When data is retrieved through `get()` the stored information is returned as a `string`. I need this information to be received in the same format before it was passed.

2) Can the following code snippet be further improved.

Comment: My guess is you are storing objects in the local storage? If so they will be strings of course. You could add another key for each data stored which contains the type of the data and then convert it to the right type in your get() method.

Comment: 1) try to push an object formatted like `{type: 'mytype', data: 'mydata_ofmytype'}` so you can always know the type represented. 2) further improved for what goal???? that sort of question is that??????

Comment: further improve refers to how the code can further improved in terms of code quality and design @morels

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localStorage: Storing Objects vs Simple Data Types in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087929/localstorage-storing-objects-vs-simple-data-types-in-different-ways)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope helps!

```js
var ClientStorageService = (function(persistent, session) {
  if(!persistent && !session) {
    throw new Error('ClientStorage Not Suppoerted'); 
  }

  function ClientStorage() {};

  ClientStorage.prototype.driver = persistent || session;
  ClientStorage.prototype.prefix = 'HELLOWORLD_';
  
  ClientStorage.prototype.usePersistent = function() {
    if(persistent) {
      this.driver = persistent;
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  };
  ClientStorage.prototype.useSession = function() {
  if(session) {
      this.driver = session;
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  };

  ClientStorage.prototype.read = function(key) {
    key = this.prefix + key;
    var data = this.driver.getItem(key);
    
    if(data) {
      
      try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      } catch(e) {}
      
      return data;
    }
    
    return null;
  };
  
  ClientStorage.prototype.store = function(key, val) {
    key = this.prefix + key.toString();
    
    try {
      val = JSON.stringify(val);
    } catch(e) {}
    
    this.driver.setItem(key, val);
    
    return this;
  };
  
  ClientStorage.prototype.clear = function(key) {
    var task = 'clear';
    
    if(key) {
      key = this.prefix + key;
      task = 'removeItem';
    }
    
    this.driver[task](key);
  };

  return new ClientStorage();
})(window.localStorage, window.sessionStorage);

ClientStorageService.store('FOO', { greetings: 'Hello World' });
var result = ClientStorageService.read('FOO');

console.log('result is', result);
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. But it throws `Uncaught TypeError: window.localStorage.bind is not a function` in the latest chrome console

Comment: I've performed a refactoring, so now works properly, hope can you accept my answer!