# Store dropdown selection and load it from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, dropdown, react-select

I want to store a couple of selection of some dropdowns where the number of these drop down is unknown because it's related to some API. So what I want is each time the page reloads it keeps the selection of each drop down remained as nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage.setItem()` to update the selected options when `onChange` event fires and retrieve the data from the last session using `localStorage.getItem()` when the component is mounted again.

Remember to serialize and deserialize the data when you set and get it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088205/9449426) for more detail on why you should do that.

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import options from "./options";

const SELECT_VALUE_KEY = "MySelectValue";

function MySelect() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const handleChange = (s) => {
    localStorage.setItem(SELECT_VALUE_KEY, JSON.stringify(s));
    setSelected(s);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const lastSelected = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(SELECT_VALUE_KEY) ?? "[]"
    );
    setSelected(lastSelected);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Select
      value={selected}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      isMulti
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63994222/store-dropdown-selection-and-load-it-from-localssroage]

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but this is when I have only one drop down, what if I have more than one selected answer at the same time ?

Comment: My answer works with multi-option `Select`. If you have multiple `Select` components, then use a unique key for each components when accessing the local storage key (in my example, the default is `MySelectValue`) @Houdakilani