# Error when trying to retrieve/get data from the local storage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```html
        const headers = new Headers({
          'access_token' : accToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });

      

      

     
        axios.post(baseURI, data, {
          headers: headers
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response;
         
        }, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
          }
        }).catch(error => {
          //this.errorMessage = error.response.data;
        })
    },
```

Error when trying  to retrieve/get data from the local storage?

I have created a login form using vuejs from which data is getting stored in the local storage, but I want to retrieve data from local storage for search purpose.

In the localstorage, i have attached screenshot. Where in my code tried getting the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your object to JSON before storing it in `localStorage`. The reason being is that many browsers treat `localStorage` as a key/value pair [strictly for strings](https://javascript.info/localstorage#strings-only) meaning that [you cannot store complex data types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088205/2073738) such as an object. By calling `JSON.Stringify(obj)` you are converting your object to a string with JSON. Then later when you access the data you need to convert it back to an object by using `JSON.parse(str)`.

For example, in your code, you would want to change this line

```js
localStorage.setItem('loggedinUser', response.data.access_token);
```

To this, so you encode the object as a string

```js
localStorage.setItem('loggedinUser', JSON.stringify(response.data.access_token));
```

Then when you retrieve the data you would change your getter from

```js
var searchItem = localStorage.getItem('anonymous_id');
```

to

```js
var searchItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('anonymous_id'));
```

That way you are parsing the string back into a proper datatype