# If user navigate to different screen or logout the session the entered form data should not vanis

Tags: html, vue.js

Here I am trying, while user enters a data in a form input fields. suppose like I have a category field and I have entered a category in that field as well in title field and I have entered a title in that field and so on. I have entered a value to the input fields and if user navigate to any other pages or if user logout from the session and again user login the entered data or value in an input field that should not vanish the value should as it is if user navigate to other screen or user logout the session. How can we achieve that in vue.js I am trying but failed. I want to achieve if user navigate to other screen or logout the session it should not vanish or refresh the entered data the data should as it is.

```
<div>
<h1>Post Ad</h1>
<p>
<input type="text" v-model.lazy="category" placeholder="Search your category"
name="category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type">
</p>

<p>
<input placeholder="Title" type="text" v-model="title" name="title" maxlength="60">
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Address" v-model="address" name="address">
<input type="text" placeholder="City" v-model="city" name="city" maxlength="100">
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" placeholder="State" v-model="state" name="state">
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip" v-model="zip" name="zip" maxlength="50">
</p>

<p>
<input  type="number" placeholder="Price" v-model="price" name="price" step="any">
</p>

<p>
<textarea name="description" v-model="description" placeholder="Ad description.."></textarea>
</p>
<button style="background-color:lightgray"id="buttonDemo" style="outline:none;" class="step1_next" @click.prevent="next()" >Next</button>
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script>
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',
    data() {
            return {
            step:1,
            category:'',
            title:'',
            address:'',
            city:'',
            state:'',
            zip:'',
            price:'',
            description:'',
    methods: {
      submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"category":this.category, "title":this.title,
                "address":this.address,
                "city": this.city,
                "state": this.state,
                "zip": this.zip,
                "price": this.price,
                "description": this.description,
                "radio_price": this.radio_price,
                "Job_title": this.model,
                },//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },

  },

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is when a user has not submitted the form and has left the page you want it to reload the data. For this you can use localstorage. If you want it to load the data in from the server, then you would need to make a call to the server and get the data back, then load it in with the [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) [life-cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

What you would want to do is hook into the Vue instance before it is destroyed by using the [`beforeDestroy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) [life-cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). Then you would want to save the data to `localStorage`. First, you would want to grab all the data you want to save or the entire data object (by using [`this.$data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)), and convert that to JSON as [localStorage cannot accept complex datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67102742/2073738). Then you would commit that to `localStorage` like so:

```js
beforeDestroy(){
    localStorage.formSave = JSON.stringify(this.$data);
}
```

Next time, when the user opens the page you want to get all the data from `localStorage` and load it back to an object. We will need to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it from a string into an object. For this, we will use a loop so we can ensure that if the data object has had fields added we are not overwriting it. For this we will tap into the the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) [life-cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

```js
mounted(){
   let dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.formSave);
   for(const key in dataFromLocalStorage){
      this.$data[key] = dataFromLocalStorage[key];
   }
}
```

If you want to protect against refreshes as well you can add [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) this will catch reload events before they happen. Then you can call [`$destroy()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy) to manually trigger the destroy lifecycle. You would either add this to the [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) [life-cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) or the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) [life-cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => this.$destroy();
```

Here is a [working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67104734-npe8p)

Comment: Hi sir thanks for the solutions. I have tried with locale storage but unable to complete. can you please tell me how can I use locale storage with my above form data.

Comment: Hello, I included a code sandbox link at the bottom of my answer. Please review what I have done and merge it with your code. My answer details in depth about how this integration works and should set you off in the right direction